# UITableView set tableview row hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom tableview cell in grouptableview. And I have one hidden. I then have to make it visible. Cell tag is 3.

This is not working my code:

```
if (self.tableView.tag == 3) {
                self.tableView.hidden = NO; //Not working.
            }
```

Just i need make a one row is visible. I hope you understand.

Comment: Refer this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670635/hiding-uitableviewcell

Comment: You are hiding your entire tableView there, not a row.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Pass the cell height `zero` for that specific cell in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` , it will automatically get hidden:-

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
      float heightForRow = 40;

      YourCustomCell *cell =(YourCustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

      if(cell.tag==3)
          return 0;
      else 
          return heightForRow;
 }
```

Add the following method to your code , it will do the trick . 
Hope it will help you .

Comment: This worked for me. I did change my code to `float heightForRow = tableView.rowHeight;` That property returns the default height if it is unset.

Comment: This does not work since cellForRowAtIndexPath: causes it to crash, because the cells do not exist yet. The height is set up before the cells are created.

Comment: According to me this is not a good solution, because when cell's are reused it may cause conflict.

Comment: when i use this i get a warning: "Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it"

Comment: I recommend Zaid Pathan's answer, even for non-swift implementations.

Comment: like @Joey said, if you have a set data source that's probably a better way to check if it's the cell you want.

Comment: You could also pass `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for cells you're not customizing if you are using automatic sizing with auto layout. Also, checking your model over a cell tag is less fragile in my opinion. You don't have to worry about bug introduced by cell reuse, etc.

Comment: Beauty! Saved a lot of effort for a workaround for my scenario!! Cheers

Answer (score 53):

In **SWIFT** you need to do two things,

1. **HIDE** your cell.    (because reusable cell may conflict)
2. Set Height of cell to **ZERO**.

Look at here,

1. **HIDE** you cell.

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let myCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID",for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

       if(indexPath.row < 2){
           myCell.isHidden = true
       }else{
           myCell.isHidden = false
       }

       return myCell
   }
   ```
2. Set Height of cell to **ZERO**.

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       var rowHeight:CGFloat = 0.0

       if(indexPath.row < 2){
           rowHeight = 0.0
       }else{
           rowHeight = 55.0    //or whatever you like
       }

       return rowHeight
   }
   ```

Using this you can remove reusable cell conflict issues.

You can do the same for **cell?.tag** also to hide specific cell by tag.

Comment: when i use this i get a warning: "Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it"

Comment: I don't understand why the need to hide the cell? How does setting the height to zero cause reusable cells to conflict?

Comment: This is actually the best answer for swift and non-swift. For me, I needed to hide the cell as well as setting the height to 0. If not hidden, I see part of the cell even though the height is zero. In my case, I have a background image on the cell

Comment: Also, remember to add the 'override' keyword infant of the function. It will then read: override  func tableView(....)

Comment: I'm also getting constraint warming issues. Anybody figure this out?

Comment: @user7097242 That's possible if you have set static height to any of your comp.

Comment: This (and all other such approaches) fails with modern, dynamic tableview cells.
How are you going to know the height of a dynamic cell?

Answer (score 1):

please refer this code :-

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
  if(section == theSectionWithoutARow)
{
    if(shouldRemoveTheRow)
        return [theArrayWithTheSectionContents count] - 1;
    else
        return [theArrayWithTheSectionContents count];
  }
   // other sections, whatever
  }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:          (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
       // blah blah standard table cell creation

    id theCellObject;

     if(indexPath.section == theSectionWithoutARow)
     {
    NSInteger theActualRowToDisplay = indexPath.row;
    if(shouldRemoveTheRow && indexPath.row >= theRowIndexToRemove)

    {
        theActualRowToDisplay = indexPath.row + 1;
    }
    theCellObject = [theArrayWithTheSectionContents objectAtIndex:theActualRowToDisplay];
}

// now set up the cell with theCellObject

return cell;
  }
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

[image: Images[![][image: ][1]]
[image]

Here is my scenario. First of all, my table view is static. And in section "Account", there should alway be only one cell displayed. LoggedInCell is displayed when user is logged in, and unLoggedInCell when user is not logged in.
One solution is to set their height zero, but you may encounter NSContraints error which is complex to be fixed.
My solution is below:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let count = super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
    if section == 0 {
        return count - 1
    }
    return count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if userForApp == nil {
            return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
        } else {
            return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0))
        }
    } else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    }

}
```

quite simple! yes?
Btw, You may have the cells height problem like me, I mean the two cells (UnLoggedInCell and LoggedInCell) have different height, we should tell the table view object that the value of cells height by doing this:

```
    var originHeightOfUnLoggedInCell: CGFloat = 0.0
    var originHeightOfLoggedInCell: CGFloat = 0.0

    func recordInitialHeightOfCells() { // called in viewDidLoad()
        self.originHeightOfUnLoggedInCell = self.unLoggedInCell.frame.height
        self.originHeightOfLoggedInCell = self.loggedInCell.frame.height
  }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            if userForApp == nil {
                return originHeightOfUnLoggedInCell
            } else {
                return originHeightOfLoggedInCell
            }
        } else {
            return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
        }
    }
```