# swift - looping a tableview subview and checking is kind only get UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

tried this code in XCode 9.2 and in iOS 11.2 in simulator works fine

```
for views in self.tableView.subviews{
            if views.isKind(of: MediaCell.self){
                print("removing the cell")
                views.removeFromSuperview()
            }else if views.isKind(of: gridTableViewCell.self){
                print("removing the cell")
                views.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
```

this code is part of a segmentedControl to change the data displayed in the tableview, the tableview has 3 datasources and 2 type of cell for displaying Data, So what I need its to remove the cell. as said in XCode 9.2 works well and remove all cell in tableview that has the required type of class, but in XCode 8.3.3 running in iOS 10.3 with iPhone 7 plus simulator it does not recognized the kind of the cell, making a debug of this just show up is type of UIVIew.
I can not remove all views in the tableview since it has a tableHeaderView. here is the initializacion in the view did load of the tableview.

```
if let _profile = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("headerView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? headerView{
        self.profileHeader = _profile
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _profile
    }
    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "MediaCell", bundle: nil)
    self.tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MediaCell")
    self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"emptyTableViewCell",bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "empty")
```

here I register the cell for **MediaCell** type which is a *UItableViewCell* with xib and xib for **emtycell**. also **gridTableViewCell** is a cell made in IB inside the viewcontroller. any ideas why the class is shown as UIVIew instead of proper uitableviewcell class.

Comment: This is not the correct way of hiding cells, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28020367/3411787) answer tells how you should hide your cells.

Comment: i want to remove the cell not hide, the idea is to remove the cell to load new Data in a diferent type of cell that's why i need to remove it not hiding

Comment: In order to remove the cell, you needs to update your cell in `tableView(_  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`.
Removing cell from superview is not a good architecture and idea.

Comment: i know its not a god idea but when you have diferents kind of cell and do a tableview.reloadData() then it may be weird behavior of tableview showing elements that were deleted from the tablewview like images and so. and of course there is a code for that in tableView(_ cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

Comment: Don't reload the whole table. Simply reload the affected cell and then return the appropriate cell type in `cellForRowAt`. Manipulating the view hierarchy is just asking for trouble.

Comment: it weird i learn to reloadData in tableview always when data changed so i goin t change the data source and perhas the type of cell, and don have to reloadData i don't see how to doit.