# Hide Table Row in UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, swift

ill try to hide a row in Swift. If i select in the function heightForRowAtIndexPath to return for the specific row height 0, then there is a problem with my content (i will be overlapped) - if i select the row everythink looks as expected.

Is this maybe a bug in swift? Or what is the correct way to hide a row in Swift (Objective C).

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633966/can-i-force-a-uitableview-to-hide-the-separator-between-empty-cells refer this..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670635/hiding-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **change number of rows** to the **(previousNumber - 1)** in this method

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

And to **reload table**:

```
 [tableView reloadData];
```

BTW: **don't forget to implement** such cases in the `tableView:cellForRowForIndexPath:` and in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to return appropriate values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That means that i delete the table or? What if i just want to hide it? The reason why is i have a table with a lot of answer possibilities - so if user (for example) selects Question 1 to "A" i will activate Question 3 and 4 (these are additional questions) - i thought the easiest way is to create the whole rows and just hide some on default and activate if needed.

Comment: It's work like you change the settings (numberOfRowsInSection will return other value) and apply them (by reloading). Reload data will just refresh the tableView, not to delete.